# Testing for a Tridion component link type (binary or component) for conditional linking

Tags: 2013, dynamic-linking, tcdl

I've searched through the Razor mediation documentation and SDL Tridion 2013 documentation, and can't seem to find the answer to my question.

**What I'm attempting to do:** Test the value of a component link in my template building block and determine if its component type is either "component" or "binary"; and then I'd like to use that information to add a target attribute depending upon the component type (component: _self, binary: _blank).

**Code context:**

```
@foreach (dynamic c in @Component.Fields.HeaderLinks) 
{
    if (@c.Link.ExternalLink != null && @c.Link.InternalLink == null) 
    {
        <li><a href="@c.Link.ExternalLink" target="_blank">@c.LinkDisplayName</a></li>
    }
    else 
    {
        <li><tcdl:Link type="Component" destination="@c.Link.InternalLink" 
        templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" linkAttributes="" textOnFail="True" 
        addAnchor="False">@c.LinkDisplayName</tcdl:Link></li>                               
    }
}
```

I'd love to be able to get the component type, and conditionally assign the target to a string variable based upon type, something like:

```
if (@c.Link.InternalLink.ComponentLinkType == binary) 
{
    String target = "_blank";
}
```

or something along those lines, and then just use the variable in  the `linkAttributes` value within `<tcdl:Link>` something like...

```
<tcdl:Link ... linkAttributes="@target">@c.LinkDisplayName</tcdl:Link>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could test for specific Schema's for example

```
if (c.Link.InternalLink.Schema.Title == "Multimedia Schema Title")
```

This would give you more control if the desired output is different based on Multimedia type (e.g. image, document, video, podcast, etc..)

You could also use

```
if(c.Link.InternalLink.TridionObject.ComponentType.ToString() =="Multimedia")
```

or

```
if(c.Link.InternalLink.Schema.Purpose == "Multimedia")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks Chris, I appreciate it!

Comment: The second method is the most direct: just getting it from the component itself. Personally, I wouldn't test with a string value, but use the Enum: ComponentType.Multimedia